# Текст заголовка вопроса в ссылке

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, ссылки

Зачем ссылка на вопрос содержит текст заголовка вопроса? Например:

[image: ссылка с именем]

При этом вопрос вполне открывается и без добавления этой части к ссылке, т.к. однозначно идентифицируется номером (`591365` в примере).

Может быть это как-то упрощает индексацию для поисковиков?

Дополнительное неудобство возникает при получении ссылки на комментарий. Например, первый комментарий к этому вопросу выдаёт следующую ссылку при попытке копирования и вставки:

> `http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4078/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b5#comment13391_4078`

Часть, содержащая `%%`, особенно удручает, когда хочешь дать ссылку на комментарий в чат. И чем длиннее название темы, тем длиннее ссылка.
Может получиться так, что уже не удастся добавить какой-то достаточно осмысленной информации после копирования ссылки в сообщение.

Comment: Мне кажется, это для людей сделано, т.е это человекопонятный урл.

Comment: @NickVolynkin но не для русских: `http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4078/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5`

Comment: @NickVolynkin при копировании этот "человекопонятный урл" превращается в тучи `%ba%d0` и т.д. Например, именно наличие этого мусора приводит к тому, что приходится использовать кнопку "поделиться", а не ссылку из браузера. К тому же если вопрос открыт его заголовок и так виден.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, я замечал. Лучшее — враг хорошего. :)

Comment: @alexolut в браузере эта каша всё равно отображается корректно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin скажите это `IE` :) Но есть и другие места, где из-за этого получается мусор. Например, [вот](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3861/176217).

Comment: Если не повредит SEO, можно было бы в транслит конвертировать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я вот думаю, может вообще надо было этот вопрос на основной сайт вынести. Но это ж будет "основано на мнениях", или не будет? Имеется в виду применимо к такого рода ссылкам вообще, а не только на SE.

Comment: @alexolut тогда уж на Мету SE. Но там может быть предвзятое мнение, мол это почти никому не нужно. Поэтому нужны примеры с разных сайтов. А ещё юникод большой, не на все буквы найдется транслит.

Comment: Ненавижу транслит.

Comment: @Qwertiy pochemu?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: если мышкой навести на [ссылку](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4078/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b5#comment13395_4078), то в подсказке  человекочитаемая строчка.

Comment: @jfs [не всегда](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287563/339911).

Comment: @alexolut посмотрите на заголовок вашего вопроса. У вас ссылка не содержит "текст заголовка вопроса..." поэтому не имеет отношения к текущему обсуждению.

Comment: @jfs не понял Вас.

Comment: @alexolut : я воспринял ссылку (без slug) в вашем комментарии как пример что в подсказке не всегда человекочитаемый slug есть (не пытался по ней пройти). Если по ссылке пройти, то похоже там баг какой-то на Firefox. В любом случае "не всегда" не имеет глубокого смысла здесь (естественно, что если есть баги, то программа себя ведёт не так как  описано—иначе бы багом это не называли).

Comment: @jfs баг FF в обрезании справа. А вот отсутствие декодирования - баг SO.

Answer (score 3):

> Зачем ссылка на вопрос содержит текст заголовка вопроса?

Чтобы человек мог иметь представление куда ссылка ведёт, не переходя по ней.

Дружелюбность для человека это основная причина. Кроме того существовало мнение, что поисковики, могли на основе самого текста ссылки её позицию менять в результатах—хотя на сколько это имело и имеет значение не ясно. [Why do some websites add Slugs” to the end of URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47427/4279)

Comment: Вы наверное совсем не обратили внимание на картинку в вопросе. К тому же, эта версия не очень хорошо стыкуется со ссылкой, полученной через пункт "поделиться".

Comment: @alexolut обратил—это никак не влияет на ответ. Почему кнопка "поделиться" не копирует человекочитаемую ссылку это хороший *отдельный* вопрос—лично я написал расширение для Pythonista, которое эту ссылку в `[title](link)` превращает. Для Chrome также есть расширение, которое ссылку при отправке комментариев на `[title](link)` заменяет. В вопросах и ответах автоматически такие ссылки в читаемые превращаются при показе.