# Ссылка на комментарий не лезет в сообщение чата

Tags: поддержка, чат, ссылки

Вот ссылка на [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517070/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2/517092?noredirect=1#comment983260_517092):

> `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517070/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2/517092?noredirect=1#comment983260_517092`

В сообщение чата она не лезет, т. к. слишком длинная:

[image: скриншот]

Как её поместить в чат таким образом, чтобы отобразилось превью комментария?

[image: скриншот превью]

Comment: Помню, тоже как-то [был недоволен этим](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4078/176217).

Comment: таки используй _поделиться_

Comment: @Grundy на комментарии-то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используй ссылки не длинного формата а-ля

```
https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5362/Ссылка-на-комментарий-не-лезет-в-сообщение-чата#comment20001_5362
```

а сокращенного

```
https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5362#comment20001_5362
```

То есть достаточно удалить заголовок вопроса из ссылки и после основного url
`https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/` оставить последовательность:

```
идентификатор#commentНОМЕР_КОММЕНТАРИЯ
```

Comment: ‏‏Р‏‏а‏‏б‏‏о‏‏т‏‏а‏‏е‏‏т‏‏!‏‏!‏‏!‏‏

Comment: Хм, я сразу так попробовал, но не сработало...

Comment: @Aid может дело в слеше всё же. то есть должно  быть так `идентификатор#`, а не `идентификатор/#`

Comment: Возможно. Стоит пофиксить баг. Хотя будет ли кто это делать?

Comment: @Aid можно не я?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вряд ли Вам дадут доступ к движку чата :) Хотя в чём проблема - открыли код, завсегдатаи пофиксили, благо что каждый первый могёт, в итоге и работа сделана, и бесплатный рабочий :)

Comment: @Aid печален тот факт, что если вставить ссылку со слешом в коммент, то по клику на него всё-таки перейдет куда надо https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5362/#comment20007_5365

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ещё один аргумент в пользу того, что движок пилили (-ят) индусы.

Answer (score 2):

Декодировать русский текст и всё заработает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, вариант. А если бы она ещё длиннее была?))

Comment: Тогда только идти к Николасу и пусть они убирают неуместное ограничение. Или, что правильней, пусть научат парсер чата выдирать комментарии **без** лишнего, в сущности, придатка из названия, только по ID.

Comment: Я думал, может какие сокращенные варианты ссылки есть, а то просто заменить название не прокатило.

Comment: Только парсер поправить. Я тоже первым делом вырезал название, но не вышло.